# OS X Yosemite Mac WD elements external hard drive

Tags: external-hard-drive, file-permissions

I have a WD 1TB external hard drive Exfat. I drag the files to the trash, but can't delete the trash. Message reads "The operation can't be completed because you don't have permission to access some of the items. None of the files are locked.I can read & write. Never had this problem before with this hard drive, only just now. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could locate the mount point in the Terminal and post the output of the command:

```
ls -al
```

This will allow us to see the permissions of the files/ folders on the drive.